# Application for Mac for line Graghs

Tags: macos, graph, line

Firstly, I must humbly apologise for my quite evident lack of drawing skills.

I have a data set that includes a count of various OS versions per date:

- day 1 may include 10 of OS version 1, 12 of OS version 2, etc;
- day 2 may include slightly different counts of the same OS versions;
- day 3 may have a NEW OS version count, etc.

Basically, it's a historical view of the count of each OS version adoption.

Try as I might, and I have the following available to me:
Mac OS X Grapher
Office 2016 Excel
Apple's Keynote and Numbers
I cannot seem to present the data in a format which is easy digestible. A colleague has suggested presenting it like this:

[image]

Which makes perfect sense. Can I get any of the aforementioned apps to present the data in this way? Nope

The data is stored like this:

- dates across horizontal axis
- OS version across the vertical axis
- counts of OS versions per day in the cells

Any idea at all if the above apps can be munged to present in this format, or if there's an app that can (free is possible)?